# Git still keeps older file names but doesn't show in status

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, git-push

I capitalized some file names (e.g. `footer.js` to `Footer.js`). But the issue is that git still keeps the record of older file names but doesn't show these files anywhere even in "git status" as well. Instead, it shows an error while switching the branches. Also, there shows nothing in git changes of VS Code.
Here is my terminal content:

```
C:\Users\DELL\frontend-development\New Repo\aidhumanity-frontend>git checkout main
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        src/components/footer.js
        src/components/header.js
        src/components/modal/login.js
        src/pages/Dashboard/dashboard.js
        src/pages/home.js
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting

C:\Users\DELL\frontend-development\New Repo\aidhumanity-frontend>git status
On branch capitalization
nothing to commit, working tree clean

C:\Users\DELL\frontend-development\New Repo\aidhumanity-frontend>git status --ignored
On branch capitalization
Ignored files:
  (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        build/
        node_modules/
```

Comment: Can you check if [`git config core.ignorecase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.14.6#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreignoreCase) is set ? If not, turn it on and see if you still have the issue: `git config --global core.ignoreCase true`